# NullPointerException at com.google.android.gms.common.a.a(Unknown Source) in my android game app

Tags: android, andengine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am getting a lot of crashing reports in my android game with this error report. Can someone tell me why is it happening.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.common.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.k(Unknown Source)
at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hk.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.e.e(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.e.d(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.i.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hk.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hj.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hj.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.gz.c(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.gy.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Though I am not able to reproduce the crash issue but certainly is has something to do with leaderboard/googleplayservices

Here is how I am initiating GameHelper in onCreate method of gameactivity class.

```
public static GameHelper mHelper;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
            // handle sign-in succeess 
            Log.d("auth","sign in successful");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
            // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
            Log.d("leaderboard","sign in failed");
        }

    };
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper.setup(listener);
}
```

And here is how I am using the gamehelper in my game scene script for opening leaderboard

```
if (GameActivity.mHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        activity.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(GameActivity.mHelper.getApiClient(), "LEADERBOARD_ID"), 1);
                        Log.d("leaderboard","already signed in so open leaderboard");
                    } else{
                        GameActivity.mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();

                        Log.d("leaderboard","is connected "+GameActivity.mHelper.getApiClient().isConnected());
                        Log.d("leaderboard","not signed in so fisrt open signin");
                    }
```

This is manifest activity code

```
<activity android:name="com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: How did you manage to publish this with `com.google.example` in the package name?  Something wrong here?  Since you've obsfucated the code, the only way we can help is to see the relevant code and hope to spot it.  I bet you haven't correctly coded the activity life cycle.  Do you have android:configChanges in your manifest?

Comment: @Simon No I am not publishing com.google.example I am just using googleplayservices gamehelper class to use google play leaderboard. Edited the question with the relevant code.

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` - this is a hack, and bad hack.  Take it out, rebuild, rotate your device and fix the bugs.  You have hidden the bugs for orientation changes (because you stopped the orientation change) but they are still there for all the other reasons your activity can be recreated.  You should understand onPause() and onResume() also.  I would bet that even with this hack on place, your app crashes when the phone rings.